# Circles Riemann sphere

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I was able to prove that the circle passing through the north pole of the Riemann sphere is mapped into a straight line. How can I prove that the circle on the Riemann sphere corresponds to a circle on the complex plane. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A complex number $x+iy$ corresponds to the point $(u,v,w)$ on the Riemann sphere with
$$
  u=\frac{2x}{r^2+1},\quad v=\frac{2y}{r^2+1},\quad w=\frac{r^2-1}{r^2+1},\qquad\text{where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$}.
$$
A circle on the Riemann sphere is the intersection of the sphere with a plane.
Write the equation of the plane as $au+bv+cw=d$. Substitute in the above coordinates and multiply by the common denominator $r^2+1$, substitute in $r^2=x^2+y^2$, and you get a quadratic equation for a circle (unless $c=d$, when the plane passes through the north pole of the Riemann sphere (a.k.a. infinity)). I leave the details up to you.

Comment: Many other proofs exist, some more geometric in nature. You'll find some of them by chasing the links under “Related” down below.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried to do exactly the same as you said, but I did not succeed, and I was thinking of seeing some more interesting solution.